# Why does findstr display everything on the same line?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to display all the `.txt` files that contain the word `hungry` in the current directory and its subdirectories, with this command:

```
findstr /si hungry *.txt
```

But I have this output:

> ```
> users\fich1.txt:hungryprojects\ll\ll.txt:Hungry
> ```

And I would like it do be displayed in different lines, like:

> ```
> users\fich1.txt:hungry
> projects\ll\ll.txt:Hungry
> ```

Any idea?

Comment: Doesn't happen here, what type are the txt files, maybe not plain ascii/ansi but utf16 eventually with a bom?

Comment: What does this have to do with `strcpy`??

Comment: @abelenky sorry I made a typo

Comment: I am quite sure this has to do with non-Windows line-breaks in the text files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the line endings are in MAC style, Carriage Return only instead of carriage return and a line feed.
You have to convert the files first.
You could take a look at dbenhams [jrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) hybrid script.